# An efficient way to create a scrolling graph in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, canvas, graph

I'm working on a project that displays incoming audio on a scrolling graph. I've used a simple but inefficient way to do this. The idea is that the audio processor continuously processes incoming audio and puts it in a rolling buffer. A separate process reads the buffer (at its own pace, with requestAnimationFrame()) and then draws line from each datapoint. At every frame the canvas is cleared and the line redrawn, with a few new points. The code looks something like this:

```
const resolution = 5000;
var data = new Array(resolution);

// --- This is done in a separate file (audioworklet processor node)
data.push(newDataPoint);
data.shift();
// --- 

const canvas = document.querySelector('.grid');
const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
ctx.strokStyle = 'black'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);


function updateCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    for (let i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
        ctx.moveTo(i * width / resolution, height);
        ctx.lineTo(i * width / resolution, height - data[i]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}
```

It works fine on fast systems but on older ones it stutters. It uses way to much processing for such a rudimentary task. I would really like to know if there's a better way to do this.

I've thought about using a translate method, but I can't figure out how to remove the points at the beginning of the path (as they would just keep accumulating). The rendering of the lines has been done, it just needs to be shifted by x amount of pixels, and the off-screen data removed.

I would highly appreciate some insights or advice!

**Edit:**
added missing curly braces

Comment: Therebis a missing `}` for your last `for` loop, could you add it where it is in your code? Otherwise if it's correctly where the indentation imploes it is, then you're doing it correctly and you shouldn't have too much trouble drawing a lot of lines (and 5K is not "a lot"). Are you sure the bottleneck is at the canvas side? Did you profile it using your dev-tools?

Comment: @Kaiido I added the brace. The specific values (such as 5k points) aren't the important things. In my real code I have several more for loops that draw different lines and text elements in different colors. The approach is what I'm curious about, though it seems from your comment there isn't much improvement to be made. I haven't profiled the code, but I have a toggle for the update frame function, which takes processing from about 80% (of a single cpu core) to 5-10%.

Comment: Redrawing the entire canvas is a standard approach, it should work like this. I guess you *could* take the `imageData` buffer of the canvas to move the image around and only draw the last line, but it shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it stutters"? Notice that you have two asynchronous processes running at their own pace, both of them in discrete steps. But there's no code that would smoothen this if the data points were not added to the buffer isochronously.

Comment: Indeed nothing particularily wrong in what you show, this issue may be in what you don't show.